# Python matplotlib scatter - different markers in one scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display some points. Here is my code:

```
plt.scatter(y[:,0],y[:,1],c=col)
plt.show()
```

And as `col` I have:

```
Col:  [1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
```

So I have points in two different colours. But I also want to have two different markers. How can I do it? `markers=col` gives an error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use one scatter plot per marker.

```
markers = ["s","o"]
for i, c in enumerate(np.unique(col)):
    plt.scatter(y[:,0][col==c],y[:,1][col==c],c=col[col==c], marker=markers[i])
```

For a way to use several markers in a single scatter plot, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303895/4124317).

Answer (score 22):

Matplotlib does not support different markers in one call to scatter. You'll have to use two different calls to `scatter`; for example:

```
plt.scatter(y[col == 0, 0], y[col == 0, 1], marker='o')
plt.scatter(y[col == 1, 0], y[col == 1, 1], marker='+')
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i have the features on one variable, `x_train` and the labels on another variable  `y_train`

So I break the problem into two parts, select the data, which is `label=0`  and draw it.

then the data with `label=1` and draw it.

```
zerodataf1=X_train[:,0][y_train==0]
zerodataf2=X_train[:,1][y_train==0]
plt.scatter(zerodataf1,zerodataf2,c='blue',marker='o',label='Not Admitted')
plt.scatter(X_train[:,0][y_train==1],X_train[:,1][y_train==1],c='red',marker='+',label='Admitted')
plt.xlabel('Exam 1')
plt.ylabel('Exam 2')
plt.title('Scatter Plot ...')
plt.legend()
```