# how to change scatter plot dot shapes conditionally?

Tags: python, matplotlib

my code is like;

```py
m = np.where(data['Education']== 'Undergraduate','*','o')
colors = np.where(data["Education"]== "Undergraduate",'r','b')
data.plot.scatter(x="Weight",y="Height",c=colors, marker=m)
plt.show()
```

it works for colours but doesn't work for marker. Please help!!

Comment: which graphing library you are using?

Comment: pandas , matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: marker takes a single value and not a list or array.
You will have to break your chart in two steps. First line for Undergraduates and the next line for non-Undergraduates. Nice discussion is here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528300/python-matplotlib-scatter-different-markers-in-one-scatter)

Comment: colors = np.where(data["Education"]== "Undergraduate",'r','b')
data.plot.scatter(x="Weight",y="Height",c=colors)
plt.scatter(data['Education'] == 'Graduate, marker = 'o' )
plt.scatter(data['Education'] == 'Undergraduate', marker='s')
plt.show()

Comment: you mean like that?

Comment: Yes something like that .. Did it work? I think you have to pass the Weight and Height attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something on the following lines  .. is my suggestion.

```py
plt.scatter(x=data.Weight[data['Education'] == 'Graduate'],y=data.Height[data['Education'] == 'Graduate'],c='r', marker='*')
plt.scatter(x=data.Weight[data['Education'] == 'Undergraduate'],y=data.Height[data['Education'] == 'Undergraduate'],c='b', marker='o')
plt.show()
```