# matplotlib scatterplot get markers on a categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot scatterplot using matplotlib:
I am using the below code to plot for multiple features

```
    columns = df_filtered.columns
    font = {'family' : 'normal',
            'weight' : 'bold',
            'size'   : 8}
    color_map={0:'b',1:'r',2:'g',3:'c',4:'y',5:'m',6:'k',7:'grey',8:'tan',9:'orange',10:'seagreen',11:'royalblue',12:'darkgrey',13:'teal'}
    label_color=[color_map[l] for l in df_filtered['test_label']]

    marker_map = {12:'o',15:'*'}
    label_marker = [marker_map[i] for i in df_filtered['DOE-id']]
    for column in columns:
        print(column)
        plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
        plt.scatter(df_filtered['Time'],df_filtered[column],c=label_color,marker=label_marker)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.ylabel(column,fontsize=20)
        plt.title(column,fontsize=8)
        plt.rc('font', **font)
        plt.savefig(str(column)+'.png',bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.show()
```

But i am getting the error:-

```
    ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '*', 'o', 'o', 'o',, ...... etc..
```

I want to color the scatters using 'test_label' column and get different shapes for the scatters using 'DOE-id' column. I think the approach I have taken for marking the scatters is wrong.

Any idea on how to get this?

Comment: [Python matplotlib scatter - different markers in one scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43528300/15497888)

Comment: An easier approach uses seaborn, e.g. `sns.scatterplot(data=df_filtered, x='Time', y=column, hue='test_label', style='DOE-id')`.  There are multiple options, getting default markers, specify a dictionary or a list.