# Matplotlib scatter plot marker type from dictionary

Tags: matplotlib, scatter

Using Matplotlib to make a scatter plot (not Seaborn, Pandas, or other high-level interface), how can I use a dictionary to specify marker types?

This example works with a color dictionary:

```
x = [4, 8, 1, 0, 2]
y = [0.1, 1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9]
name = ["A", "A", "B", "A", "B"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(x, y, name), columns=["x", "y", "name"])

colors = {"A": "red", "B": "blue"}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(
    x=df["x"],
    y=df["y"],
    facecolors="none",
    edgecolors=df["name"].map(colors),
)
```

[image]

But the following throws an error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`:

```
markers = {"A": "v", "B": "D"}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(
    x=df["x"],
    y=df["y"],
    facecolors="none",
    edgecolors=df["name"].map(colors),
    marker=df['name'].map(markers),
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303895/9245853

Comment: @BigBen wow, is this still true? linked post is a few years old, does matplotlib still not support multiple markers?

Comment: From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html): 
The marker style. marker can be either an instance of the class or the text shorthand for a particular marker. Matplotlib does not support multiple markers in one scatter call. One option is to loop, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528300/python-matplotlib-scatter-different-markers-in-one-scatter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments by @BigBen, it looks like Matplotlib doesn't support multiple markers. @BigBen linked to a couple of example work-arounds, but I found the following works best for me because it allows me to explicitly relate a keyword to a marker style at the beginning of my code, regardless of what subset of `df` I am working with. (Real-life data has a dozen "name"  values, and I am working with various and mixed subsets based on attributes in other columns.)

```
x = [4, 8, 1, 0, 2]
y = [0.1, 1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9]
name = ["A", "A", "B", "A", "B"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(x, y, name), columns=["x", "y", "name"])

colors = {"A": "red", "B": "blue"}
markers = {"A": "v", "B": "D"}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for name, group in df.groupby("name"):
    group = group.copy()
    m = markers.get(name)

    ax.scatter(
        x=group["x"],
        y=group["y"],
        facecolors="none",
        edgecolors=group["name"].map(colors),
        marker=m,
        label=name,
    )
    ax.legend(loc="lower right")
```

[image]